# Множественное число

Tags: этимология

Всем известны слова, обозначающие времена года. Это "весна", "лето", "осень" и "зима". Вот захотелось от них образовать множественное число. Но не получается. Только лишь с зимами все хорошо. Ведь можно сказать "я пережил десяток зим", "зимы у нас холодные". А как быть с остальными словами? Почему так получается? Понятно также, что слова "лета"(р.п.-"лет") - это по смыслу скорее не множественное число от "лето", а от "год".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы поостерегся категорично утверждать, что у слов лето и осень нет множественного числа. Во всяком случае выражения типа "вёсны и осени" (а то и лета и осени, но о лете - ниже), "пять осеней" и проч. встречаются в разговорной и поэтичечкой речи.

~1.Юрий Коваль. Листобой (1972)   [омонимия снята] Все примеры (1) ― Ей скоро паспорт получать, ― шутит Булыга. ― Шестнадцать осеней. Не годами― осенями отмечают возраст гончих собак. [Юрий Коваль. Листобой (1972)] [омонимия снята] ←…→

~2.Примечание на рябине (2002) // «Вечерняя Москва», 2002.12.09   [омонимия не снята] Все примеры (1) На одном месте они цветут 3-4 года. Глубина их осеней посадки ― 5-8 см. Это зимостойкое растение не боится весенних заморозков. [Примечание на рябине (2002) // «Вечерняя Москва», 2002.12.09] [омонимия не снята] ←…→

~3.Борис Левин. Инородное тело (1965-1994)   [омонимия не снята] Все примеры (1) Сколько осеней, сколько зим Я провел на земле один, Сколько долгих и скучных лет Я по глупости свел на нет, Сколько рюмок допил до дна… [Борис Левин. Инородное тело (1965-1994)] [омонимия не снята] ←…→

~4.Анатолий Найман. Славный конец бесславных поколений (1994)   [омонимия не снята] Все примеры (1) Всего за свою жизнь я ездил помогать колхозу осеней десять. [Анатолий Найман. Славный конец бесславных поколений (1994)] [омонимия не снята] ←…→

~5.Григорий Козинцев. «Тут начинается уже не хронология, но эпоха...» (1940-1973)   [омонимия не снята] Все примеры (1) Если нет никаких золотых осеней и Левитанов, а есть гнусный мир провинции. [Григорий Козинцев. «Тут начинается уже не хронология, но эпоха...» (1940-1973)] [омонимия не снята] ←…→

~6.Василий Белов. Привычное дело (1967)   [омонимия не снята] Все примеры (1) Сквозь дрему накатывались к ней видения прошедших весен, лет, осеней и зим, но она тут же забывала эти видения. [Василий Белов. Привычное дело (1967)] [омонимия не снята] ←…→

~7.Вс. В. Иванов. Бронепоезд № 14.69 (1922)   [омонимия не снята] Все примеры (1) Детей она принесла пятерых ― из года в год, пять осеней ― когда шла сельдь, и не потому ли ребятишки росли светловолосые ― среброчешуйники. [Вс. В. Иванов. Бронепоезд № 14.69 (1922)] [омонимия не снята] ←…→

(Нац корпус).

Это только начало списка, дальше копать времени нет. Но имена авторов убеждают. А это только одна форма, родительный множнственого.

Касательно "лето". Отчленить употребление слова "лет" в значении "годов" от множественного числа "лет" без смыслового и лексического анализа текста не представляется возможным. Поэтому приходится ограничиваться отдельными примерами. Во всяком случае шестой номер из предыдущего списка представляется довольно убедительным.Но возникает вопрос законности употребления такой формы. Безусловно, "[пять] лет" является исторически образованием от "лето" - год. Но даёт ли это основание считать его и в современном языке множественныи для "лето", я не берусь судить. Хотя выражения типа "сколько лет, сколько зим" заставляют считать именно так. Словари несколько расходятся, "Русское словесное ударение" (М. В. Зарва) признаёт лЕта (лет, лЕтам) множественным для лето.

Comment: Согласна. Поторопилась. Про поэтическую и разговорную речь вовсе не спорю.

Comment: Второй пример некорректен. "Глубина их осеней посадки". Вы явно не вдумались в смысл. Должно быть "Глубина их осенней посадки".

Вообще, честно говоря, формы множественного числа звучит весьма нелепо. "Осенями"? "Вёснами"? Как-то громоздко. Хотя примеры убедительны и показывают, что действительно это возможно. Спасибо большое. Развеяли мои сомнения.

Comment: >>>Второй пример некорректен.   
Допустим. И что?

Comment: Ну, его лучше убрать =) Я думаю, что в нем просто опечатка. И получается, что там не существительное, а прилагательное - "осенней"

Comment: Это будет на грани подтасовки эксперимента.  
Данные-то получены пронграммно, по запросу "осеней".
Я думаю, все и так сообразят, что этот пример случаен.

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что речь идет про сайт http://www.ruscorpora.ru/ ?

Comment: Да, конечно. 
Ну совсем точно - о проекте, которому этот сайт принрадлежит. 
Это очень авторитетный источник, можно сказать - государственный.
http://www.ruscorpora.ru/corpora-about.html

Answer (score 1):

Слова "зима", "весна" имеют формы множественного числа - зимы, вёсны. Слова "лето" и "осень" - не имеют множественного числа. Почему - трудно сказать. Может, традиция. Может (в случае с "лета") - стремление избежать омонимии.